# How to change first value in list of two lists

Tags: python, list, reference

I would like to know how to change the first value of such list:

`[100][TimeStamp]
 [200][Timestamp]
 [300][Timestamp] 
       etc`

My code for now looks like this:

```
bitrateList = []
for x in range(SCANTIME):
    stop = time.time() + 1
    while (time.time()<stop):
        totalSize += len(sock.recv(bufferUDP))      
    bitrateList.append([[totalSize], [time.ctime()]])
    print(bitrateList[x])
    totalSize = 0

for x in range(len(bitrateList)):
    for y in range(1):
        bitrateList[x][y] = bitrateList[x][y]*8
        print(bitrateList[x][y])
```

However accessing to first element of each row as I did results in this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTwnm.jpg

How can should I change referring to first element of each row in my list in order to look like this?

`[800][TimeStamp]
 [1600][Timestamp]
 [2100][Timestamp] 
       etc`

Comment: provide your list in a proper format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bitrateList[x][y]` when `x = 0` and `y = 0` is `[100]` not `100`. So when you multiply `[100]` by 8, due to operator overloading you get = `[100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]`. You need to access the first element of that list. So, try this:

```
bitrateList = []
for x in range(SCANTIME):
    stop = time.time() + 1
    while (time.time()<stop):
        totalSize += len(sock.recv(bufferUDP))      
    bitrateList.append([[totalSize], [time.ctime()]])
    print(bitrateList[x])
    totalSize = 0

for x in range(len(bitrateList)):
    bitrateList[x][0][0] = bitrateList[x][0][0]*8
    print(bitrateList[x][0])
```

Comment: Thank you also, this solution removes unnecessary `for-loop` from my code.